# Configuring spray-servlet to avoid request bottleneck

Tags: akka, spray

I have an application which uses `spray-servlet` to bootstrap my custom Spray routing Actor via `spray.servlet.Initializer`. The requests are then handed off to my Actor via `spray.servlet.Servlet30ConnectorServlet`.

From what I can gather, the `Servlet30ConnectorServlet` simply retrieves my Actor out of the ServletContext that the `Initializer` had set when the application started, and hands the `HttpServletRequest` to my Actor's receive method. This leads me to believe that only **one** instance of my Actor will have to handle all requests. If my Actor blocks in its `receive` method, then subsequent requests will queue waiting for it to complete.

Now I realize that I can code my routing Actor to use `detach()` or a `complete` that returns a Future, however most of the documentation never alludes to having to do this.

If my above assumption is true (single Actor instance handling all requests), is there a way to configure the `Servlet30ConnectorServlet` to perhaps load balance the incoming requests amongst multiple instances of my routing Actor instead of just the one? Or is this something I'll have to roll myself by subclassing `Servlet30ConnectorServlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and now I understand better how `spray-servlet` is working. It's not `spray-servlet` that dictates the strategy for how many Request Handler Actors are created but rather the plumbing code provided with [the example I based my application on](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-servlet/simple-spray-servlet-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/Boot.scala).

My assumption all along was that `spray-servlet` would essentially work like a traditional Java EE application dispatcher in a handler-per-request type of fashion (or some reasonable variant of that notion). That is not the case because it is routing the request to an Actor with a mailbox, not some singleton HttpServlet.

I am now delegating the requests to a pool of actors in order to reduce our potential for bottleneck when our system is under load.

`val serviceActor = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(config.SomeReasonableSize).props(Props(Props[BootServiceActor])), "my-route-actors")`

I am still a bit baffled by the fact that the examples and documentation assumes everyone would be writing non-blocking Request Handler Actors under spray. All of their documentation essentially demonstrates non-Future rendering `complete`, yet there is no mention in their literature that maybe, just maybe, you might want to create a reasonable sized pool of Request Handler Actors to prevent a slew of requests from bottle necking the poor single overworked Actor. Or it's possible I've overlooked it.